# Clicking select menu opens other one in slack modal view

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I am creating a modal using views.open API of Slack. I have 1 channel picker and 1 user picker. Whenever I click on channel picker it opens the user picker instead as if I clicked it. Am I misusing the API or is this a bug? 
Below is JSON code that you can use to visualize the modal in Slack Block Kit Builder

```
{
    "type": "modal",
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Search",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "submit": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Search",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "close": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Cancel",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Enter topics:"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "multi_static_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "topic",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 1",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-0"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 2",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 3",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "context",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "Entering multiple topics will filter snippets containing all of them"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Only show results from following user"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "static_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Choose a user",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 1",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-0"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 2",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 3",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "or",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Only show results from following channel"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "static_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Choose a channel",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 1",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-0"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 2",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Choice 3",
                            "emoji": true
                        },
                        "value": "value-2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue disappeared 3 days ago. I guess silent update fixed it